Attempting to create league table from results data
I have a dataset of 4 teams and I am trying to create a league table of their results
In the sheet below (see screenshot and markdown), the dataset is in columns A:I and the League Table is in columns K:R.
The league Table shows the results for each team. With the help of @rocknfreakshow, I have managed to determine the For and Against columns for each of the 4 teams. What I am struggling with are the Wins/Draws/Losses for each team.
To take the "Cheltenham Knights" team, they had 2 Wins (scores of 4-1 and 3-2) and 1 Draw (score of 2.5 - 2.5). I have written the Win/Draw/Loss results for all 4 teams in the League Table (highlighted in light brown in the screenshot).
Two other points:

A win = 2 points, a draw - 1 point and a loss - 0 points.
If the teams are playing at home, they appear in the dataset in column A, and if the teams are playing away, they appear in column F.

Screenshot of dataset and league table



Cheltenham Knights




Stroud Badgers




League Table
Played
Wins
Draws
Losses
For
Against
Points




Rob Cannall
2253
B
1

Moyers
2230
W
0

Stroud Badgers
2
1
1
0
6
4
3


David Horton
1934
W
0.5

Peter Kirby
2018
B
0.5

Wotton Hall Lions
1
0
0
1
2
3
0


Jim Beaty
1925
B
1

Alex Carey
1870
W
0

Cheltenham Knights
3
2
1
0
7
5.5
5


Alun Richards
1678
W
0.5

Rob Wilden
1762
B
0.5

Gloucester
2
0
1
1
2
3
1


Tom Brown
1584
B
1

Zoe Moyers
1411
W
0














4




1































Stroud Badgers




Gloucester














Duncan Dicks
2076
W
1

Benjamin Lappin
1938
B
0











Pete Dhonau
1991
B
1

Matthew Hammond
1837
W
0











John Jenkins
1979
W
1

Edward Small
1827
B
0











Clive Walley
1906
B
1

Andrew James
1683
W
0











Harry Davison
1840
W
1

Mitchell Darkes
1332
B
0














5




0































Cheltenham Knights




Wotton Hall Lions














Nigel Hosken
2095
W
0

Ian Robson
2228
B
1











Dan Lambourne
2087
B
1

Mike Ashworth
2117
W
0











Richard Freeman
1994
W
0.5

Robert Ashworth
1856
B
0.5











Tristram De Piro
1984
B
1

Alexandru Moldovan
1821
W
0











Gary Andriessen
1926
W
0.5

Rich Maclannan
1816
B
0.5














3




2































Gloucester




Cheltenham Knights














Benjamin Lappin
1932
B
0

Rob Cannall
2262
W
1











Matthew Hammond
1831
W
1

Paul Masters
2039
B
0











Edward Small
1821
B
0.5

David Horton
1933
W
0.5











John Lightowler
1690
W
1

Joe Ingram
1911
B
0











Andrew James
1679
B
0

Jonathon Day
1857
W
1














2.5




2.5













=BYCOL( 
   MAP(A:A, F:F, LAMBDA(hm_, aw_, IF(hm_<>"",
     IFNA(LET(
       adj_, IF(hm_="CHELTENHAM Knights",1,
         IF(aw_="Cheltenham Knights",6,#N/A)),
       dif_, OFFSET(hm_,6,2+adj_)-OFFSET(hm_,6,9-adj_),
       IF(dif_>0, {1,0,0}, IF(dif_<0,{0,0,1}, {0,1,0})))),))),
   LAMBDA(col_, SUM(col_)))

Offsets values such that Cheltenham Knights' opponent's score is always subtracted from theirs:

Win: difference > 0
Loss: difference < 0
Tie:  difference = 0

Returns each result as a {w, l, t} array (eg. Win: {1,0,0} with the appropriate column populated with a 1 and the rest with 0 so that all the result arrays returned can be summed by column, resulting in {ttl wins, ttl losses, ttl ties} for Cheltenham Knights'.
All Statistics
Seems like unnecessary duplication to calculate each stat individually given it is reusing the same data.
Here is the same formula adapted to include all the statistics including the labels sorted by points descending, then by games played ascending.
Version 1
=LET(htRng,A:A, atRng,F:F, hsRng,D:D, asRng,I:I,
   teams, FILTER({htRng, atRng}, htRng<>"",
     MOD(ROW(htRng)-ROW(INDEX(htRng,1))+1,8)=1),
   scores, FILTER({hsRng, asRng}, hsRng<>"",
     MOD(ROW(hsRng)-ROW(INDEX(hsRng,1))+1,8)=7),
   hTeams,INDEX(teams,,1), aTeams,INDEX(teams,,2),
   hScores,INDEX(scores,,1), aScores,INDEX(scores,,2),  
   unqTeams, UNIQUE({hTeams;aTeams}), 
   boxscores, BYROW(unqTeams, LAMBDA(team, BYCOL(
     MAP(hTeams, aTeams, hScores, aScores, LAMBDA(h, a, hs, as, 
       IF(REGEXMATCH(h&a, team), LET(
       adj, IF(h=team, 0, 1), sFor, IF(h=team,hs,as),
       sAg,IF(h=team,as,hs), dif_,sFor-sAg,
       wtl_,IF(dif_>0, {1,1,0,0}, IF(dif_<0,{1,0,0,1}, {1,0,1,0})),
       {wtl_, sFor, sAg, SUMPRODUCT(wtl_,{0,2,1,0})}),))),
   LAMBDA(col, SUM(col))))),
   {"Team", "Played", "Wins", "Draws", "Losses",
    "For", "Against", "Points";
    SORT({unqTeams,boxscores},8,0,2,1)})

Version 2
=LET(calc, LAMBDA(x,y, FILTER(x, INDEX(x,,1)<>"", MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),8)=y)),
  i,LAMBDA(x,y, INDEX(x,,y)), 
  teams,calc({A1:A,F1:F},1), scores,calc({D1:D,I1:I},7),
  boxscores,WRAPROWS(TOROW(
    MAP(i(teams,1), i(teams,2), i(scores,1), i(scores,2),
      LAMBDA(ht,at,hs,as, 
        IF(hs>as,{ht,1,1,0,0,hs,as,2,at,1,0,0,1,as,hs,0},
        IF(hs=as,{ht,1,0,1,0,hs,as,1,at,1,0,1,0,as,hs,1},
                 {ht,1,0,0,1,hs,as,0,at,1,1,0,0,as,hs,2}))))),8),
  sumCols,{"Col1", INDEX("SUM(Col"&SEQUENCE(1,7,2)&")")}, 
  qCols,JOIN(", ", sumCols), 
  qLabels,"LABEL "& JOIN(", ", INDEX(sumCols & " '"& {"Team", "Played",
    "Wins", "Draws", "Losses", "For", "Against", "Points"}& "'")), 
  QUERY(boxscores, "SELECT "& qCols &" GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY 
    SUM(Col8) DESC, SUM(Col2) "& qLabels))

Explanation

Your game results are each 8 rows (7 with data followed by an empty row). The team names are always in row 1 of that sequence and the scores are in row 7.  Using that pattern in the FILTER formula stored in calc allows creating:

An array of team names, teams, by using MOD to filter {A1:A,F1:F} for row numbers that are a multiple of 8 with exactly 1 remainder: MOD(x, 8)=1 (ie. the first row of an 8-row group) and also not blank rows. Each row represents a game, and the first column is the home team and the second is away:

Cheltenham Knights    Stroud Badgers  
Stroud Badgers        Gloucester  
Cheltenham Knights    Wotton Hall Lions   
Gloucester            Cheltenham Knights


scores is returned in much the same way but using MOD(x,8)=7:

4    1
5    0
3    2
2.5  2.5


A stored INDEX formula, i is used to split teams and scores  into separate home and away arrays as the arguments for a MAP function that passes one value from each column into a LAMBDA function that stores that game's home team in ht, away in at, home team's score in hs and away in as.

The LAMBDA function will create the box scores for the home team and away team in one step which will result in a one-row array for that game that is 16 columns. It does this by comparing the scores:

If the Home team won then the box scores will be:
TM GP  W  T   L  For Ag. Pts. TM GP  W  T  L  For Ag. Pts.
{ht, 1, 1, 0, 0, hs, as,  2,  at, 1, 0, 0, 1, as, hs, 0}

Using the first row of data from teams and scores:
ht=Cheltenham Knights, hs=4, at=Stroud Badgers, as=1

Team                GP  W   T  L  For Ag. Pts.  Team          GP  W  T  L For Ag. Pts.
{Cheltenham Knights, 1, 1, 0, 0,  4,   1,   2, Stroud Badgers, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4,  0}


The 4 games in the example return:



Team
GP
W
T
L
SF
SA
PTS
Team
GP




Cheltenham Knights
1
1
0
0
4
1
2
Stroud Badgers
1


Stroud Badgers
1
1
0
0
5
0
2
Gloucester
1


Cheltenham Knights
1
1
0
0
3
2
2
Wotton Hall Lions
1


Gloucester
1
0
1
0
2.5
2.5
1
Cheltenham Knights
1






A TOROW function converts the table to a single row and the WRAPROW function wraps the row at every 8 columns and boxscores is now:



Team
GP
W
T
L
SF
SA
PTS




Cheltenham Knights
1
1
0
0
4
1
2


Stroud Badgers
1
0
0
1
1
4
0


Stroud Badgers
1
1
0
0
5
0
2


Gloucester
1
0
0
1
0
5
0


Cheltenham Knights
1
1
0
0
3
2
2


Wotton Hall Lions
1
0
0
1
2
3
0


Gloucester
1
0
1
0
2.5
2.5
1


Cheltenham Knights
1
0
1
0
2.5
2.5
1




The last step involves using QUERY to sum all the numeric columns, group by team name, and the column labels.  Because there are 8 columns and a lot of repetition, two additional variables are created to dynamically generate the QUERY function's query argument: sumCols and qLabels.



Absolutely brilliant @blindspots.  Thank you so much.  I really want to study your formula and try to figure out how it all works but it's a little overwhelming.  Any tips on how to approach this?

It works beautifully, @blindspots.  Thanks again!  Now I have to try to figure out how it all works - you must have a ton of experience with spreadsheets.

Have deleted a number of comments @blindspots.

I added a version 2 of the formula.  It isn't more or less performant than the first but it avoids nested LAMBDAs and may be easier to wrap your head around. Then uses QUERY to aggregate the totals by team.

Thanks for Version 2 and Explanation.  The only thing not correct in Version 2 is the points total in the last column.  (This was evident when I tested on a larger dataset than the one originally given in this question.)

Fixed. Last row didn't give any points for the away win. Corrected by changing the last 0 to a 2 ie. From {ht,1,0,0,1,hs,as,0,at,1,1,0,0,as,hs,0} to  {ht,1,0,0,1,hs,as,0,at,1,1,0,0,as,hs,2}

Many thanks.  Works perfectly.  Now my studying begins :)
